# Determine 2G or 3G connection

Tags: debian, modem, wvdial

I am using WvDial to dial my USB modem up to my ISP. But how can I tell what network I am connected to: 2G or 3G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only see the signal strength by adding this line into `wvdial.conf` :

`Init4 = AT+CSQ`

The Values are Min-Max = `0 - 30`.

For the type of connection you can only see it by the `lights` on the device.

EDIT:

`AT^SYSINFO` gives different useful information, among these is the connection type.

Comment: Yes, I am also using the signalstrength commands. I also tried this command: `AT+COPS?` which gives this: `+COPS: 0,0,"Siminn",2` but I do not known what the numbers mean.

Comment: @Adlersson - see this nice post - [link](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcops-plmn-selection/), it has description about output.

Comment: Thank you! I think `AT^SYSINFO` provides the answer. It says I am in WCDMA mode, which I think is in the 3G range. I guess EDGE would be 2G.

Comment: @DAdlersson - see this link for [Difference between GSM, GPRS, EDGE, 3G, WCDMA and HSDPA](http://amit2810.blogspot.in/2011/03/difference-between-gsm-gprs-edge-3g.html)